# JavaScript - Reading file with HTML5 FileReader

Tags: javascript, file

I'm currently learning JavaScript and I'm struggling to read a txt file and use its contents in the program, what I have so far:

```
fileBtn.addEventListener("change", function()
{ 
 var content = [];
 var file = fileBtn.files[0];
 readFile(file, function(data)
 {
   console.log(JSON.parse(data));
   //content.push(JSON.parse(data)) doesn't work, data is undef.
 });

});
```

and a function readFile

```
function readFile(file, f)
{
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(evt)
  {
   f(evt.target.result);
  };
   reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

My txt file is currenty only containing a "1", and it logs this number to the console but I can't work with it, if I try to push it into an array the values is suddenly undefined. My goal is to use the content of the file in the program later on

Answer (score 0):

1 . no need to use JSON.parse if the text file only contain string . 
`data` is containing all the text file content

2 . you need to put  `var content = [];`
globally and not inside the function readFile

follow this snippet of code i think it will solve your problem

---

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
        Custom Upload
    </label>
    <input id="file-upload" type="file" />
    <input id="log-content" type="button" value="Click Me"/>

</body>



<script>
    var content = [];

    function readFile(file, f) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (evt) {
            f(evt.target.result);
        };
        var text = reader.readAsText(file);
    }
    var fileBtn = document.getElementById("file-upload");
    var logContnt = document.getElementById("log-content");

    logContnt.addEventListener("click", function () {
        alert(content);
    })
    fileBtn.addEventListener("change", function () {
        var file = fileBtn.files[0];
        readFile(file, function (data) {
            content.push(data);
        });

    });
</script>



</html>
```

[image]

Comment: `JSON.parse("1") !== "1"` so point 1 is irrelevant. Point 2 might be the problem though.

Comment: you wrong . 

when you use JSON.parse on a parsed value you get this exception  

    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at i.html:37
    at FileReader.reader.onload (i.html:24) 



try it yourself change 
            content.push(data);
 to 
            content.push(JSON.parse(data));

Comment: If the text file is just `1` then `reader.result` will be `"1"`, and if you pass this to `JSON.parse()` it will output `1`. Try it yourself, with a text file made only of `1`. OP didn't complain about this error, and if what they are trying to read is intended to be in JSON format, there is no reason to tell them not to use it. (Ps: JSON.parse will coerce whatever you pass to it to a string, so passing a Number won't throw)

Comment: Thanks, it works kinda but how can go about it without using a global array and another button? If I try to do the same thing without logContnt the array content is again undefined

Comment: its just an easy way to display the content value .why do you think after loading the text file  content  value is undefined?

Comment: Don't know, I have the same code as you now, but if I try to log the contents without the button, the content of the array is undefined

Comment: please add a snippet of code . where do you use the console.log(content) .

Comment: Well, I think its undefined because the console.log(content) is executed before the file is read because of the asynchronity. I used console.log directly below fileBtn.addEventListener

Comment: This code runs once when the the script it's loaded of course it will be undefined when the page it's loaded to see it's content put the console log after the content.push(data) statement

Comment: petro did you try the example here ? is it work? can you close this